# jmeter tcp response text

Tags: java, testing, jmeter

I have a server located on a private ip. When I send a frame by tcp, the server returns another frame.

Example:

Send: 64029384942023841230349

Received: 0394820123954812340989

The problem is that jmeter does not close the connection to receive that frame. I have to close the connection manually, but I do not need that. I need to jmeter close the connection automatically when I receive the frame.

Any ideas ?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you using TCP sampler? If so, please share the screenshot

Comment: Yes, I'm using tcp sample. Also, I can solve it, use the EOL property to indicate the end of the response string with the corresponding value. Thank you very much!

Comment: That's correct. Specify EOL as per your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved!

Use the EOL property to indicate the end of the response with the corresponding value!